# Trouble running Flask alongside uWSGI/Nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm currently facing issues running my Flask app, and I suspect it's related to a recent restructure of my main app files. I'm struggling to identify the source of the problem and would greatly appreciate any assistance.

When I try to run the app using the flask run command, the website is only accessible on the default port 5000. Attempting to access the website at http://127.0.0.1:5000/ results in the error message "This site can't be reached 127.0.0.1 refused to connect."

I've tried changing the port number in the run.py file to a custom value, but despite updating the code, the logs still indicate that the app is using port 5000. Additionally, I've verified that port 5000 isn't being used by any other process.

I have tried disabling the firewall and verifying that there are no other network issues, but the problem still persists.

I'm uncertain whether the issue is with my code or the server configuration, but I suspect it may be related to the recent restructuring of the main app files.

**Notably, uWSGI has no problem running on the domain or IP address.**

Any insights or solutions to this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Below, I have provided the relevant code for context:

**Evidenca-2.0/wsgi.ini**

````
[uwsgi]

module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = wsgi.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true```
````

**Evidenca-2.0/wsgi.py**

```
from run import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**Evidenca-2.0/run.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_minify import Minify
import os
import logging

from apps.config import config_dict
from apps import create_app, db

# Configure the app
app_config_mode = os.getenv('FLASK_ENV', 'development')
try:
    app_config = config_dict[app_config_mode.capitalize()]
except KeyError:
    logging.warning(f'Invalid config mode: {app_config_mode}. Defaulting to development mode.')
    app_config = config_dict['Development']

app = create_app(app_config)

# Initialize extensions
db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
minify = Minify(app=app, html=True, js=False, cssless=False)

# Configure logging
log_file_name = 'app.log'
if app_config.DEBUG:
    log_level = logging.DEBUG
else:
    log_level = logging.INFO
logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file_name, level=log_level)

if app_config.DEBUG:
    logging.debug(f'DEBUG            = {app_config.DEBUG}')
    logging.debug(f'FLASK_ENV        = {os.getenv("FLASK_ENV")}')
    logging.debug(f'Page Compression = {"FALSE" if app_config.DEBUG else "TRUE"}')
    logging.debug(f'DBMS             = {app_config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI}')
    logging.debug(f'ASSETS_ROOT      = {app_config.ASSETS_ROOT}')
    logging.debug(f'UPLOAD_FOLDER    = {app_config.UPLOAD_FOLDER}')

# Start the app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000, threaded=True)
```

**Evidenca-2.0/apps/config.py:**

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from flask import Flask


class Config:
    basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

    # Set up the App SECRET_KEY
    SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY', 'S#perS3crEt_007')

    # Set up the database configuration
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.getenv('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI', 'mysql+pymysql://aviat:admin@localhost/Evidenca')
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

    # Flask-User settings
    USER_APP_NAME = "Flask-User QuickStart App"      # Shown in and email templates and page footers
    USER_ENABLE_EMAIL = False      # Disable email authentication
    USER_ENABLE_USERNAME = True    # Enable username authentication
    USER_REQUIRE_RETYPE_PASSWORD = False    # Simplify register form

    # Assets Management
    ASSETS_ROOT = os.getenv('ASSETS_ROOT', '/static/assets')

    # File Upload
    UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.getenv('UPLOAD_FOLDER', '/uploads')
    ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

    # Set up logging
    LOG_FILE_NAME = os.getenv('LOG_FILE_NAME', 'app.log')
    LOG_LEVEL = os.getenv('LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG')

    # Set up the MariaDB database engine
    ENGINE = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, echo=True)

    # Set up the app configuration
    DEBUG = os.getenv('DEBUG', False)
    SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
    REMEMBER_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
    REMEMBER_COOKIE_DURATION = 3600

    if DEBUG:
        print('DEBUG             = ' + str(DEBUG))
        print('FLASK_ENV         = ' + os.getenv('FLASK_ENV'))
        print('Page Compression  = FALSE')
        print('DBMS              = ' + SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
        print('ASSETS_ROOT       = ' + ASSETS_ROOT)
        print('UPLOAD_FOLDER     = ' + UPLOAD_FOLDER)


class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False

class DebugConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True


# Load all possible configurations
config_dict = {
    'Production': ProductionConfig,
    'Development': DevelopmentConfig,
    'Debug': DebugConfig
}
```

**Evidenca-2.0/apps/_*init*_.py:**

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Copyright (c) 2023 - Aviat Networks

This module sets up the main application and initializes its components. It also
registers the necessary extensions and blueprints for the application.
"""

from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from importlib import import_module

# Initialize flask app, SQLAlchemy database, and LoginManager
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy()
login_manager = LoginManager()


def register_extensions(app):
    """
    Register the necessary extensions for the application.
    """
    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)


def register_blueprints(app):
    """
    Register the blueprints for the application.
    """
    for module_name in ('authentication', 'inventory'):
        module = import_module('apps.{}.routes'.format(module_name))
        if module_name == 'authentication':
            app.register_blueprint(module.auth_bp, url_prefix='/auth')
        if module_name == 'inventory':
            app.register_blueprint(module.inventory_blueprint)


def configure_database(app):
    """
    Configure the database for the application.
    """

    # Initialize the database before the first request
    @app.before_first_request
    def initialize_database():
        db.create_all()

    # Remove database session after each request
    @app.teardown_request
    def shutdown_session(exception=None):
        db.session.remove()


def create_app(config):
    """
    Create and configure the Flask application.

    :param config: The configuration object for the application.
    :return: The Flask application instance.
    """
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config)
    register_extensions(app)
    register_blueprints(app)
    configure_database(app)
    return app
```

The odd thing is that it works, if I set it up like this: `flask run -h 192.168.X.X` How come it doesn't work on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you use the loopback interface IP address: *127.0.0.1* or  *[localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)*.

This address can only be accessed by itself. You can google it to get more information if you want.
If you use the `flask run` command, you should specify the host and port, otherwise flask will use the default paras *127.0.0.1:5000*.
So you can try use this command:

```
flask run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 80
```

Your Flask application could be accessed by every IP address of you host with port 80. If your server has two or more network interfaces, and the IP address is *192.168.1.1/24*, *10.10.1.1/8*, you can access your application through *http://192.168.1.1* and *http://10.10.1.1*.

Last one, your application could work with `flask run -h 192.168.X.X`. That means your server IP address is *192.168.x.x*, and the port is 5000 (default). So you can access the your application by *http://192.168.x.x:5000*.

Consider your server IP address may be changed or your code will deploy to other server, use `flask run -h 0.0.0.0` is *strongly* recommended.

Comment: BTW.  the code `app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000, threaded=True)` in run.py doesn't work, because you use flask cmd to run,  you can use python run.py to make the code work.